# PHP access to mail queue on Linux server

Tags: php, linux, email, queue

I wonder if someone can help with a query I have. My server recently had an email account hacked and subsequently a large amount of spam appear in the mail queue. I've changed the password on the email account in question and used qmHandle to remove the spam from the mail queue. I would like to prevent this from happening again and I was wondering if it would be possible for PHP to access the mail queue and run a cron job that could run every hour and run a script to alert me if the mail queue exceeds a set amount of mails so I could be alerted and react accordingly? My server is Linux running Redhat if that makes any difference?

Many thank in advance.

Comment: mailqueue will be owned/operated by root. Unless you want to run PHP as root, it will have no rights to the queue.

Comment: install something like nagios/cactus monitoring that runs as a service on the machine and can monitor your queue at an OS level and then they have a web front end to monitor it with.  This is one of my nagios graphs http://i39.tinypic.com/n2oq5g.png

Comment: thank you for the swift reply. If I ran the script as root is it simply a case of listing the number of files in the mail directory?

Comment: @Dave - thank you - that look amazing - looks complicated to install though. My server is managed by Rackspace as I now nothing about the running of a server and I'm pretty sure they won't support it :(

Comment: If its rackspace you have 2 options you can pay them a one off to setup/configure it all for you or you can follow some step by step tutorials there are loads out there that you can just copy and paste the commands from if you want look on how-to forge for munin and nagios mail queue monitoring

Comment: @Dave I did speak to rackspace but they were very much "you can add some software but we won't support it" - I'd be to worried about messing it up to have a go myself.

Comment: Perhaps you should find a freelancer to do the work for you then thats what I usually do when I need server configuration done I know the basics but not enough to fiddle on production servers so I pay sys admins to do it for me

Comment: @dave - I'm running Redhat which doesn't look like it's cover on how-to-forge

Comment: @dave - I think you might be right. That might be the best way forward.

Comment: Check this link out for many how to's for redhat based distro's http://bit.ly/1kCU4nY

Comment: I found this:

http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?292492-Simple-check-amount-of-messages-in-qmail-queue-including-bulk-mail-using-qread

Looks like this chap had the same problem as myself. What do you think?

Comment: you would have to cron that script (its a shell script not php) to run as root every xxx minutes or once an hour or something it'll then email you the output it'll annoy you fast.

Answer (score 0):

As i don't know which Maildaemon you use, i can just throw some things to think about:

1. To display the que, use "mailq" (on a Debian/Postfix system)
2. To access it from php, use "sudo" (execute a command as root from non priviledged user)
3. Maybe filter/group it by adding "grep" to "mailq"

Comment: mailq is postfix/sendmail only I believe not all MTA's

Comment: Hello, the server uses QMail so I guess if I run a php script as root I would be able to list the mail directory contents like I would a web directory?

Comment: not really mailq gives you a single text stream you'd have to regex it to pull out the useful information as its full of crap

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using qmail, and you have qmHandle on the server, it's fairly straight-forward.  `qmHandle -s` will give you some statistics, including the number of messages in the remote queue.  The remote queue contains outgoing messages that are queued for delivery.  You can cobble together a one-liner using grep and cut, which will give you just the count of the number of messages in the remote queue, like so: `qmHandle -s | grep remote | cut -d: -f2`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need PHP to do that. A simple bash script ran by cron would do it. Somethig like that:

```html
nbline=`mailq|wc -l`
if [ $nbline -gt $seuilMails ]
then
  echo -e "\nSeuil queue postfix dépassé ($nbline lignes)" >> $msgFile
  sendmail=true
  else echo -e "\nQueue postfix normale" >> $msgFile
fi
if [ "$sendMail" == true ]; then
        mailto_admins "$sujet" "$msgFile"
fi
```